# Trouble getting hurdle model to converge for continuous zero inflated data

Tags: r, regression, model, continuous-data, zero-inflation

I'm trying to fit a generalized mixed effect model for zero inflated semi-continuous data in R using the `GLMMadaptive` package. I have 13 variables but even just getting 2 of them (like Temperature and Salinity) to run would be great and I can expand from there. `hog.cpue` is the dependent variable, the rest are predictor. I can't get it to converge. I've tried adding the `iter_EM = 0, max_coef_value = 150` which cleared up the first 2 errors but still cant get it to fully run.

I've tried this code

```
> km1 <- mixed_model(hog.cpue ~ Temperature + Salinity, random = ~ 1 | Reference, data = hogobsA2, 
+                    family = hurdle.lognormal(), n_phis = 1,
+                    zi_fixed = ~ hog.cpue, iter_EM = 0, max_coef_value = 150)
Warning message:
glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
```

The full base code for the `hurdle.lognormal()` function of the `GLMMadaptive` package can be found here https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/ZeroInflated_and_TwoPart_Models.html#two-part-mixed-effects-model-for-semi-continuous-data but most of it is way over my head.

If anyone can see what I'm doing wrong or suggest a better way to analyze this data that would be awesome! I've tried 9 different ways to get zero inflated models to run and always run into a snag. On the page provided above there are two other methods, but I'm not sure how to tell which is the best for my data. The one I tried is the only one that specified continuous data.

This is the non-zero part of my data before transformation
[image]

This is the non-zero part of my data after log transformation
[image]
It's slightly more normal but still heavily skewed.

This is a sample of my data including all zeros, this is cpue catch data so the zeros are important and not caused by errors, there just weren't any of this particular species caught in that set......

```
structure(list(Reference = c("BBM2009110105", "BBM2012090101", 
"BBM2009080109", "BBM2013070110", "BBM2011080103", "BBM2015100105", 
"BBM2009090104", "BBM2008060208", "BBM2018070702", "BBM2012060104", 
"BBM2016070103", "BBM2010050102", "BBM2014070102", "BBM2010050109", 
"BBM2010050105", "BBM2017110107", "BBM2008110202", "BBM2010090102", 
"BBM2015080108", "BBM2011060103", "BBM2012060106", "BBM2018060103", 
"BBM2018090108", "BBM2009110110", "BBM2014070101", "BBM2010080106", 
"BBM2011090101", "BBM2013050108", "BBM2012090110", "BBM2010050107", 
"BBM2014080406", "BBM2009110106", "BBM2009070109", "BBM2017080103", 
"BBM2013050104", "BBM2017090105", "BBM2009080104", "BBM2016110106", 
"BBM2017100104", "BBM2015060107", "BBM2013100103", "BBM2013080403", 
"BBM2018100105", "BBM2014090102", "BBM2016110108", "BBM2018080401", 
"BBM2013060107", "BBM2015070110", "BBM2016100103", "BBM2013070102"
), NODCCODE = c("6177010102", "6189021300", "6177010102", "6177010100", 
"6177010102", "8762020101", "5509051200", "5509051200", "8839010901", 
"5509051202", "5509051202", "8820020102", "6177010102", "6177010102", 
"6189021300", "6189021300", "6189021300", "6177010102", "6177010102", 
"5509051202", "6177010102", "8839010901", "8747020202", "6189010301", 
"5509051202", "8747010803", "5509051202", "8820023901", "8839010901", 
"6177010102", "6177010100", "6189021300", "5509051200", "6177010100", 
"8820020102", "6189021300", "5509051200", "5509051202", "6189021300", 
"6189010301", "8762020101", "8839010901", "6177010100", "5509051202", 
"6189021300", "8839010901", "5509051202", "5509051202", "6177010100", 
"6177010102"), Depth = c(-1.34375613733192, 0.858911039351898, 
-0.609533745103979, -0.364792947694666, 0.858911039351898, 0.614170241942585, 
-0.120052150285353, -1.46612653603657, 0.247059045828616, -0.364792947694666, 
2.20498542510312, -0.120052150285353, 0.00231824841930331, 0.491799843237929, 
0.491799843237929, 3.30631901344503, 0.736540640647242, -1.34375613733192, 
1.59313343157984, 1.96024462769381, 0.736540640647242, -0.120052150285353, 
0.369429444533272, -1.34375613733192, 0.12468864712396, -0.364792947694666, 
0.858911039351898, 0.369429444533272, -0.364792947694666, -0.854274542513292, 
-0.487163346399323, 0.614170241942585, -0.120052150285353, -0.976644941217948, 
0.614170241942585, 0.736540640647242, -0.609533745103979, 1.10365183676121, 
1.83787422898915, 1.71550383028449, 1.10365183676121, -0.120052150285353, 
0.491799843237929, 0.369429444533272, -0.487163346399323, 1.10365183676121, 
-0.487163346399323, -0.364792947694666, -1.0990153399226, 0.858911039351898
), Temperature = c(-1.8772752877957, -0.109512367327292, 0.738045197280849, 
0.30215844976809, 0.713829266863474, -0.472751323587924, 0.326374380185466, 
0.931772640619853, 1.00442043187198, -0.133728297744667, 1.19814787521098, 
-0.182160158579419, 0.447454032272344, 0.0842150760117116, -0.133728297744667, 
-1.80462749654357, -1.99835493988258, 0.616965545193972, 1.00442043187198, 
0.689613336446098, -0.157944228162043, 0.399022171437593, 1.07706822312411, 
-1.61090005320457, 0.374806241020217, 0.616965545193972, 0.52010182352447, 
0.229510658515965, 0.108431006429087, 0.205294728098589, 0.883340779785102, 
-1.6835478444567, 0.52010182352447, 0.883340779785102, 0.0842150760117116, 
-0.0368645760751657, 0.7864770581156, -0.642262836509552, -1.00550179277018, 
0.544317753941845, -1.41717260986557, 0.495885893107094, 0.132646936846462, 
0.568533684359221, -0.545399114840051, 0.859124849367726, 0.762261127698225, 
1.29501159688048, -0.424319462753173, 0.229510658515965), Conductivity = c(-1.21896005737695, 
-0.631273978174986, 0.503568105801218, -0.104383010614606, 1.45602485485267, 
0.625158329084382, 0.321182770876471, 1.29390455714179, 0.280652696448749, 
-1.25949013180467, 1.43575981763881, -1.01630968523834, 0.442772994159636, 
-1.56346569001258, -1.15816494573537, 0.787278626795268, 1.29390455714179, 
-0.469153680464099, 0.787278626795268, 1.09125418500318, 0.321182770876471, 
0.05773728709628, -0.975779610810618, -1.72558598772347, 0.483303068587356, 
-1.09736983409378, 0.969663961720015, 0.503568105801218, -0.73259916424429, 
-2.15115176921454, 0.503568105801218, 0.604893291870521, 1.45602485485267, 
-2.00929650871752, 0.564363217442799, 0.645423366298243, 0.402242919731914, 
0.321182770876471, 0.929133887292294, 0.280652696448749, 0.463038031373495, 
-1.78638109936505, 0.54409818022894, 0.361712845304192, 0.361712845304192, 
-0.347563457180935, -0.327298419967074, 1.37496470599723, -1.64452583886802, 
-0.813659313099732), pH = c(1.56498992191445, -0.0820106753442685, 
-0.0820106753442685, -1.72901127260298, 0.329739473970408, -0.493760824658945, 
-0.0820106753442685, -0.905510973973622, -0.0820106753442685, 
-0.0820106753442685, -0.0820106753442685, -0.493760824658945, 
-0.0820106753442685, 0.329739473970408, -0.493760824658945, -0.0820106753442685, 
-0.493760824658945, 0.329739473970408, 0.329739473970408, 1.15323977259977, 
0.329739473970408, -0.0820106753442685, -0.0820106753442685, 
0.741489623285092, -0.0820106753442685, -0.0820106753442685, 
0.329739473970408, 1.15323977259977, 0.329739473970408, 1.15323977259977, 
1.15323977259977, 0.329739473970408, 0.329739473970408, -0.905510973973622, 
1.15323977259977, -0.493760824658945, 0.329739473970408, -0.493760824658945, 
0.329739473970408, 0.329739473970408, -0.0820106753442685, -1.3172611232883, 
-0.493760824658945, 1.15323977259977, -0.493760824658945, -1.3172611232883, 
0.329739473970408, -0.0820106753442685, -1.3172611232883, -1.3172611232883
), Salinity = c(-1.12894483601917, -0.599890886264641, 0.486061957968336, 
-0.0708369365101144, 1.46063502330562, 0.653131626311871, 0.3189922896248, 
1.29356535496209, 0.263302400176955, -1.18463472546701, 1.40494513385778, 
-0.961875167675634, 0.458217013244413, -1.49092911743016, -1.10109989129525, 
0.848046239379328, 1.34925524440993, -0.460666162645029, 0.76451140520756, 
1.09865074189463, 0.346837234348723, 0.0683877871094981, -0.961875167675634, 
-1.60230889632585, 0.486061957968336, -1.0454100018474, 0.987270962998941, 
0.513906902692258, -0.683425720436409, -2.07567295663253, 0.486061957968336, 
0.653131626311871, 1.46063502330562, -1.93644823301292, 0.597441736864025, 
0.680976571035793, 0.402527123796568, 0.374682179072646, 0.987270962998941, 
0.291147344900878, 0.513906902692258, -1.71368867522154, 0.569596792140103, 
0.374682179072646, 0.402527123796568, -0.349286383749339, -0.293596494301495, 
1.34925524440993, -1.54661900687801, -0.766960554608177), DissolvedO2 = c(2.3781250547958, 
0.102780135236268, -0.124754356719685, -0.57982334063159, -0.124754356719685, 
0.102780135236268, -0.750474209598555, 0.0458965122472799, -0.636706963620578, 
1.18356897202704, -0.466056094653614, 0.159663758225256, -1.77437942340034, 
1.24045259501603, 0.0458965122472799, 0.557849119148173, -0.0678707337306965, 
-0.0109871107417085, 0.102780135236268, -0.466056094653614, 0.0458965122472799, 
-0.181637979708673, 0.330314627192221, 1.80928882490591, -1.4899613084554, 
-0.29540522568665, 0.159663758225256, 1.35421984099401, 0.956034480071091, 
2.66254316974074, 0.728499988115138, 0.444081873170197, 0.387198250181209, 
-0.636706963620578, 0.500965496159185, -2.0019139153563, -0.238521602697661, 
0.557849119148173, 0.159663758225256, -0.0678707337306965, 0.785383611104126, 
-0.466056094653614, -0.978008701554508, -0.864241455576531, 0.614732742137162, 
-1.60372855443338, 2.60565954675175, -0.124754356719685, -0.636706963620578, 
-0.57982334063159), Secchi_depth = c(-1.38143088689724, -0.674407019999457, 
-0.250192699860789, -1.38143088689724, 1.16385503393477, 0.881045487175659, 
0.0326168468983229, -1.09862134013813, 0.456831167036991, -0.250192699860789, 
2.71930754110989, 0.456831167036991, 0.174021620277879, 0.739640713796103, 
0.739640713796103, 3.56773618138722, 1.30525980731433, -1.38143088689724, 
2.01228367421211, 0.0326168468983229, 0.739640713796103, 0.0326168468983229, 
-0.674407019999457, -1.38143088689724, 0.315426393657435, -0.250192699860789, 
1.16385503393477, 0.598235940416547, -1.09862134013813, -0.815811793379013, 
-0.391597473240345, 0.881045487175659, 0.0326168468983229, -0.957216566758569, 
0.881045487175659, 1.02245026055522, -0.250192699860789, 1.87087890083255, 
1.58806935407344, 2.15368844759166, 0.174021620277879, -1.80564520703591, 
-1.09862134013813, -0.533002246619901, -0.391597473240345, 0.174021620277879, 
-0.674407019999457, -0.250192699860789, -1.09862134013813, 0.174021620277879
), Seagrass_habitat_descriptor = c(0.812860286079953, NaN, -1.19050642465534, 
NaN, -0.188823069287694, -2.19218978002299, 0.812860286079953, 
NaN, 0.812860286079953, 0.812860286079953, NaN, 0.812860286079953, 
NaN, NaN, 0.812860286079953, NaN, NaN, 0.812860286079953, -1.19050642465534, 
NaN, NaN, 0.812860286079953, -0.188823069287694, 0.812860286079953, 
NaN, 0.812860286079953, -1.19050642465534, 0.812860286079953, 
-0.188823069287694, 0.812860286079953, 0.812860286079953, -0.188823069287694, 
-1.19050642465534, 0.812860286079953, -0.188823069287694, -2.19218978002299, 
0.812860286079953, -0.188823069287694, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, -1.19050642465534, -2.19218978002299, -2.19218978002299, 
NaN, 0.812860286079953, NaN), Distance_to_edge = c(0.855428244226582, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.855428244226582, -1.22577651024171, 0.855428244226582, 
NaN, NaN, 0.855428244226582, NaN, 0.855428244226582, NaN, NaN, 
0.855428244226582, NaN, NaN, -0.805331105298617, -1.22577651024171, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -1.22577651024171, NaN, NaN, -1.20475423999455, 
NaN, NaN, 0.855428244226582, NaN, 0.855428244226582, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, -1.22577651024171, 0.855428244226582, 0.855428244226582, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -1.22577651024171, -1.22577651024171, 
-1.22577651024171, NaN, 0.771339163237964, NaN), BycatchQuantity = c(-0.0418322197301852, 
-0.448703271363022, -0.768387669074537, 1.992523038434, -0.564952143258119, 
-0.332454399467926, -0.21620552757283, 0.830034319483037, -0.50682770731057, 
-0.332454399467926, -0.681201015153215, 0.248789960007556, -0.448703271363022, 
-0.797449887048311, -0.623076579205667, -0.826512105022085, 0.248789960007556, 
0.248789960007556, 0.0744166521649111, 0.830034319483037, -0.623076579205667, 
0.248789960007556, -0.564952143258119, -0.0999566556777333, -0.797449887048311, 
-0.739325451100763, 4.89874483581141, 1.70190085869626, -0.448703271363022, 
-0.623076579205667, -0.332454399467926, -0.198768196788565, 1.41127867895852, 
-0.0418322197301852, 0.132541088112459, -0.21620552757283, -0.21620552757283, 
2.57376739790948, -0.611451692016157, 0.190665524060007, -0.739325451100763, 
-0.21620552757283, -0.0418322197301852, 3.27126062928006, -0.623076579205667, 
-0.332454399467926, 1.992523038434, 1.70190085869626, 1.41127867895852, 
1.70190085869626), Dist_tow = c(1.12364856132588, 0.216133493763229, 
0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, 1.12364856132588, 0.216133493763229, 
0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, -1.59889664136207, 
0.216133493763229, 1.12364856132588, 0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, 
-1.59889664136207, 0.216133493763229, -0.691381573799419, -0.691381573799419, 
0.216133493763229, -5.22895691161265, 1.12364856132588, 0.216133493763229, 
0.216133493763229, 1.12364856132588, 0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, 
-3.41392677648736, 0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, 1.12364856132588, 
0.216133493763229, 1.12364856132588, -0.691381573799419, 0.216133493763229, 
0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, 
0.216133493763229, -3.41392677648736, 0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, 
0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, 
0.216133493763229, -0.691381573799419, 0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229
), Bearing = c(-0.373608799006711, -0.67731447002544, 0.436272990376564, 
0.841213885068202, -1.13287297655353, -1.58843148308162, -0.778549693698349, 
1.86368964416459, -0.778549693698349, 1.14491955608693, -0.869661395003968, 
-1.2847258120629, 1.75233089812439, 0.537508214049473, -1.2847258120629, 
-0.67731447002544, 0.07182618515409, -0.67731447002544, 0.537508214049473, 
-0.373608799006711, 0.233802543030745, 0.294543677234491, 0.132567319357836, 
-0.0699031279879832, 1.75233089812439, -0.373608799006711, 1.44862522710566, 
-1.58843148308162, -0.0699031279879832, 0.638743437722383, 1.44862522710566, 
-1.2847258120629, -0.0699031279879832, 1.79282498759355, -0.67731447002544, 
0.335037766703654, 0.233802543030745, -1.29484933443019, 1.95480134547021, 
0.0313320956849262, -0.373608799006711, -0.67731447002544, -1.13287297655353, 
1.54986045077857, 1.0639313771486, 0.2844201548672, 0.841213885068202, 
0.739978661395292, -1.01139070814604, -1.18349058838999), hog.cpue = c(-0.283463862297085, 
-0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, 
-0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, 1.02183821998587, 
-0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, 
-0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, 
-0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, 
3.63244238455178, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, 
-0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, 1.02183821998587, 
-0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, 
-0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, 
-0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, 
1.02183821998587, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, 
1.02183821998587, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, 
-0.283463862297085)), row.names = c(135L, 320L, 109L, 379L, 242L, 
544L, 114L, 18L, 696L, 293L, 572L, 142L, 441L, 149L, 145L, 676L, 
62L, 181L, 527L, 222L, 295L, 682L, 717L, 140L, 440L, 176L, 250L, 
357L, 329L, 147L, 459L, 136L, 99L, 642L, 353L, 654L, 104L, 615L, 
663L, 506L, 402L, 385L, 724L, 461L, 617L, 704L, 366L, 519L, 602L, 
371L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: ok I can't see the whole dataset, but you can try a few things, zi_fixed = ~ hog.cpue , this is quite bad, the zero inflation cannot be dependent on the dependent variable.. if you think it is just missing at random, use zi_fixed =~ 1

Comment: I noticed you have negative values.. did you actually take the log? It should be the actual values, and you apply the lognormal() distribution

Comment: Yeah I accidentally included the log transformed data. Here is my whole data as CSV... https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rDEciVwTVWs3TlVV_hi4WNalEt6cjVHY

Comment: Hi @Johnny5ish... thanks for sharing.. i will try to take a look at the data sometime tomorrow..

Comment: @StupidWolf you have been more than helpful. Thank you so much...  I got the first part to run with your advice about zi_fixed dependent variable stuff. The model spits out a bunch of plots I don't understand and the last part wont fit parameters. please see this question here as it may be more informative. I posted a new one that may give you more insight. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/467040/statistical-analysis-help-fitting-2-stage-or-hurdle-model-on-zero-inflated-semi