# Statistical analysis. Help fitting 2 stage or hurdle model on Zero inflated semi-continuous data

Tags: r, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, model, zero-inflation

Here is a link to My data

drive.google.com/open?id=1rDEciVwTVWs3TlVV_hi4WNalEt6cjVHY

I'm trying to model cpue (response variable) and tell whether any of the explanatory variables have a significant influence on it. I know that a need some sort of hurdle or 2 stage model, and I've tried some very complex Generalize linear mixed effect 2 stage models from `GLMMadaptive` explained here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GLMMadaptive/vignettes/GLMMadaptive_basics.html , but they are way over my head. I;ve also tried this compound poisson gamma model from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21807118/r-codes-for-tweedie-compound-poisson-gamma. I can't get either to run completely, but more importantly I'm not even sure if I'm going down the right (model) path. My ultimate goal is to run a multiple regression on all these variables. Then I have 2 other zones of data to compare against to look for simlarities and differences, or see if my explanatory variables have the same influence in all three zones. I have looked at every stack overflow and cross validated question that i think is even remotely related, but nothing works. I think that is because my data is so skewed even after removing the zero part, and log transforming the non zeros. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
library(GLMMadaptive)
library(tweedie)
library(lattice)
library(nloptr)
```

```
# This is a Generalized linear mixed effects hurdle model to analyze 
hog.2stage <- mixed_model(hog.cpue ~ Temperature + Salinity, 
                          random = ~ 1 | Reference, data = hogobsA2, 
                          family = hurdle.lognormal(), n_phis = 1,
                          zi_fixed = ~1, iter_EM = 1)
#summary of model
summary(hog.2stage)

# refit the model with an increasing number of quadrature points.
hog.2stage_q11 <- hog.2stage
hog.2stage_q15 <- update(hog.2stage_q11, nAGQ = 15)
hog.2stage_q21 <- update(hog.2stage_q11, nAGQ = 21)

#combine new quadrature point values
hogA.models <- list("nAGQ=11" = hog.2stage_q11, "nAGQ=15" = hog.2stage_q15, "nAGQ=21" = hog.2stage_q21)

# extract from the model the estimated parameter for the fixed effects (using function fixef()), 
# for the random effects, and the log-likelihood (using function logLik()):
extract <- function (obj) {
  c(fixef(obj), "var_(Intercept)" = obj$D[1, 1], "logLik" = logLik(obj))
}


sapply(hogA.models, extract)


#compare to a simple glm
hogA.glm <- glm(hog.cpue ~ Temperature + Salinity, data = hogsAonly, family = Gamma())

#Anova comparing the 2 stage to a regular glm
anova(hog.2stage, hogA.glm, test = FALSE)



###WORKING but not sure what all this is.
############################
# An effects plot for the mean subject (i.e., with random effects equal to 0)
nDF <- with(hogobsA2, expand.grid(Temperature = seq(min(Temperature), max(Temperature), length.out = 15),
                            Salinity = seq(min(Salinity), max(Salinity))))

plot_data <- effectPlotData(hog.2stage, nDF)

#requires package "lattice"
xyplot(pred + low + upp ~ Temperature | Salinity, data = plot_data,
       type = "l", lty = c(1, 2, 2), col = c(2, 1, 1), lwd = 2,
       xlab = "Temperature", ylab = "Log Salinity")

expit <- function (x) exp(x) / (1 + exp(x))
xyplot(expit(pred) + expit(low) + expit(upp) ~ Temperature | Salinity, data = plot_data,
       type = "l", lty = c(1, 2, 2), col = c(2, 1, 1), lwd = 2,
       xlab = "Temperature", ylab = "Probabilities")

# we put the two groups in the same panel
my.panel.bands <- function(x, y, upper, lower, fill, col, subscripts, ..., font, 
                           fontface) {
  upper <- upper[subscripts]
  lower <- lower[subscripts]
  panel.polygon(c(x, rev(x)), c(upper, rev(lower)), col = fill, border = FALSE, ...)
}

xyplot(expit(pred) ~ Temperature, group = Salinity, data = plot_data, upper = expit(plot_data$upp),
   low = expit(plot_data$low), type = "l", col = c("blue", "red"), 
       fill = c("#0000FF80", "#FF000080"),
       panel = function (x, y, ...) {
         panel.superpose(x, y, panel.groups = my.panel.bands, ...)
         panel.xyplot(x, y, lwd = 2,  ...)
       }, xlab = "Temperature", ylab = "Probabilities")



##################### This part not working
# An effects plots for the marginal probabilities
plot_data_m <- effectPlotData(hog.2stage, nDF, marginal = TRUE)

expit <- function (x) exp(x) / (1 + exp(x))
xyplot(expit(pred) + expit(low) + expit(upp) ~ Temperature | group, data = plot_data_m,
       type = "l", lty = c(1, 2, 2), col = c(2, 1, 1), lwd = 2,
       xlab = "Temperature", ylab = "Probabilities")
#####################
```

````
#Tweedie Compund Poisson gamma model

summary(hogobsA2$hog.cpue)

#histogram of zero inflated data
hist(hogobsA2$hog.cpue)

#histograms of just non zero cpue data
hist(hogsAonly$hog.cpue)



library(tweedie)

#Test different powers and compare to 

qqTweedie <- function(xi,p,mu,phi) {
  names <- c("Poisson","Gamma","Inverse Gaussian","Positive Stable")
  plot(qtweedie(p,xi,mu,phi),quantile(hogsAonly$hog.cpue,probs=p),
   main=paste0("Power = ",xi," (",names[xi],")"))
  qqline(hogsAonly$hog.cpue,prob=c(0.25,0.75), col="blue", lty=2,
         distribution=function(p) qtweedie(p,xi,mu,phi))
}
p <- seq(0.01,0.99,length=800)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
lapply(c(1:4),qqTweedie,p=p,mu=1,phi=1)

# QQ plot of ideal power xi = 3  
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
xi <- 3
plot(qtweedie(p,xi,1,1),quantile(hogsAonly$hog.cpue,probs=p),main=paste0("Power = ",xi))
qqline(hogsAonly$hog.cpue,prob=c(0.25,0.75), col="blue", lty=2,
       distribution=function(p) qtweedie(p,xi,1,1))


# require package "nloptr"
F <- function(params){ # Note: xi, Q, and p are defined external to F
  mu  <- params[1]
  phi <- params[2]
  return(sum(Q - qtweedie(p,xi,mu,phi))^2)
}
xi <- 3
Q <- quantile(hogsAonly$hog.cpue,p) 
opt <- nloptr(x0=c(mu=0.0293,phi=.01), eval_f=F, ub=c(5,.1), lb = c(1,0), 
          opts = list(algorithm="NLOPT_LN_COBYLA",maxeval=100,print_level=1))
opt$solution
```
````

Comment: I took a look at the data quickly. As far as I can see, you don't really have enough complexity in your data to warrant such a complicated model.. I mean, you have a lot of zeros (which we cannot tell what they are), and how would you expect temperature to have such a complex effect?

Comment: I think the effect of temperature is clear ... higher temperature and higher response...

Comment: Can you recommend a simpler model that would account for all the zeros. The zeros matter as there were no fish found there. Thanks as usual.